# Input placeholder style on first character

Tags: html, css, placeholder

I have an input with a placeholder. But I want to apply a style on this placeholder to have my first Character in Bold ( and other font-size)

```
<input oninput="writeInk()" onclick="clickInput2()" id="search_input_id" type="text" 
class="headerSelectAndInputPrinter" style="width:250px; margin-left: 8px;height: 42px" 
placeholder="2 - Second Input" />
```

i'm looking for "2" in bold and in an other font-size.
I have found nothing about that... All propositions I found don't work...

https://jsfiddle.net/4gabefLu/

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot style the first-letter of a placeholder with a css rule.

You can build a pseudo placeholder with javascript and style the first letter with `::first-letter` selector.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter

Your input become:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <input oninput="writeInk()" onpaste="writeInk()"  onkeyupe="writeInk()" onclick="clickInput2()" id="search_input_id" type="text" class="headerSelectAndInputPrinter" style="width:250px; margin-left: 8px;height: 42px" />
  <span class="pseudoPlaceholder">2 - Second Input</span>
</div>
```

You can style with css your selector

```
.wrapper{
   position: relative; 
}


.pseudoPlaceholder{
   pointer-events: none;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 15px;
   transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

.pseudoPlaceholder::first-letter{
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

and handle with javascript the pseudo placeholder:

```
function writeInk(){
   if($("#search_input_id").val() == ""){
       $(".pseudoPlaceholder").show();
   }else{
       $(".pseudoPlaceholder").hide();
   }
}
```

This is the result: https://jsfiddle.net/01w2abx7/19/